# Ruby question on how to create a numbered list 1-10 etc

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby looking to create a simple numbered list 1-10 , 11,20 all the way until it hits 90-100. I have tried a few things such as a while loop. Here is some code I been working on.

```
while n== 1
   if n== 1
     puts "1-10"
   elsif n == 11
     puts "11-20"
   end

 end
```

Currently this loop will of course be infinite because no count also the elsif wont run because it's stuck in the 1-10 (I'm not sure 100% why I presume because no counter?) I appreciate any feedback and help thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? Should it be a string or a list of strings? or List of lists?

Comment: Nothing is changing the value of n. Try adding "n += 1" so that n increments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the string values out (with the ranges) you can do this:

```
(1..100).step(10) do |n|
  puts "#{n}-#{n+9}"
end
```

Prints:

```
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
41-50
51-60
61-70
71-80
81-90
91-100
```

Also, without step (this is probably a more desirable version):

```
(0..9).each do |n|
  puts "#{n*10+1}-#{n*10+10}"
end
```

Comment: `step` is pretty amazing.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip.

Answer (score 1):

Since you originally wanted a cycle, not a block, look how it was possible.

```
n = 1
until n == 101
  puts "#{n}-#{n + 9}"
  n += 10
end
```

or

```
n = 1
while n != 101
  puts "#{n}-#{n + 9}"
  n += 10
end
```

In both cases will print

```
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
41-50
51-60
61-70
71-80
81-90
91-100
```